# Error linking html files in a navigation bar in Django

Tags: django

I'm using django and trying to link one of my links to a html file in my navbar. I have all my html files stored in a folder called personal and in a subfolder in personal called includes. I am trying to link my register link to the Register.html file, but it is always saying it can not find it and current url Register.html is not a recognized url pattern. This is how I referenced it in my home.html file which is where my navbar is located:

```
<li class="active"><a href="/Register.html">Register <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
```

my urls.py file looks like this:

```
"""mysite URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin



urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',include('personal.urls'))]
```

I have looked on this website for an answer but I can't seem to find one. I have tried manipulating my views.py file and my urls.py file but they just end up making the webapp not work at all. My question is how do I resolve the error so that it recognizes those html files?

Comment: If you are referring to the html files the path is as follows Desktop\Django_tutorial\mysite\personal\templates\personal\includes, I have my Register file in there and as for my home html file that is in the folder named personal one up from the includes folder

Comment: Please take a look at the django tutorial, you never reference a template file directly in another template